# Error when importing .ASC file into QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, import

I have downloaded a [freely available digital terrain model](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=356e41a416664d2d9ecca13067c847c2) from a geological survey. The file consists of a folder with .gdb files and a folder with .asc raster images. I have been unable to import either of these successfully into QGIS (I am running 3.26.1 Buenos Aires). I have tried to import individual .asc files using Layer > Add Layer > Add Raster Layer and get the error "*filename* is not a supported raster data source." From other searching on this forum, I have possibly identified that the .asc files having some non-numeric gaps may be the issue, but I do not know how to fix this. I have not been able to convert the .asc file to .csv either.

Comment: I couldn't do anything with the .gdb files, but the .asc files work just fine. They are in EPSG:3163. Drag-n-drop.

Comment: Thank you! I am relatively new and self-taught. I did not check to ensure I had the correct CRS.